# Android APK - intent issue

Tags: java, android, android-intent, apk

i was wondering about the behavior of my applicaton.

At the moment I'm developing an application on android. The app works fine without crashes or bugs when i just hit the "Run" Button to build and install it directly on my smartphone.

When i generate a signed APK or just a unsigned APK, install it and start the app, the app crashes when i start another intent.

I dont have a clue why this work only when i directly start it with Android Studio. Would you give me a hint please ? I don't get any further.

### Heres the java Code from the activity, which starts other activites (Without imports)

```
public class activity_settingsselector extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    Intent obj_soundconfig;
    Intent obj_roundconfig;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_settingsselector);

        obj_soundconfig = new Intent(this, activity_soundconfiguration.class);
        obj_roundconfig = new Intent(this, activity_roundconfiguration.class);
    }

    void start_activitySoundconfig (View view)
    {
        startActivity(obj_soundconfig);
    }

    void start_activityRoundconfig (View view)
    {
        startActivity(obj_roundconfig);
    }
}
```

### And here is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.steffenhemme.equimetric">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".activity_splashscreen"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activity_settingsselector" />
        <activity android:name=".activity_soundconfiguration" />
        <activity android:name=".activity_roundconfiguration" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: uninstall your app from your device. Clean your android studio code and run again may be you get some thing in logcat

Comment: crash mean obviously logcat so question is where are they? where you are hiding them?

Comment: Thx for the very quick answer. I will do that when i get home today. Hope i get some infos in logcat. Is there maybe a permission issue in my Manifest ? Need the "Settingselector" Activity the permission to start an Activity ? The big question is where are the difference between running it in Andorid Studio and generateand install a APK manually ?

Comment: Hey im back. Really thank you both. The answer was that i have to use a onClickListener in the javafile instead of using android:onClick in the XML Layoutfile.